# How can I calculate the difference between different times

Tags: mysql, sql, database

hope you are well today.

I need some help in this case, need for each day, for each taxiID, the sum of the hours worked with passengers ( ent_pickup_time, ent_dropoff_time) and without passengers, ( ent_requested time, ent_dropofftime). 
For example the taxi 003001 in the day march 3 of 2015 worked 3 hours with a passenger and 3 hours and a half without a passenger. 
I have tried a million queries, and no one of them worked so far :(

My last query :

```html
 SELECT substring(hex(ent_id), 1, 3) AS fleetId, substring(hex(ent_id), 4, 16) AS taxiId, 
  (ent_requested_time), (ent_pickup_time), (ent_dropoff_time) , (ent_fare), (ent_distance),      
     SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ent_dropoff_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(ent_pickup_time))) AS Con_Pasajero,
     SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ent_pickup_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(ent_requested_time))) AS Sin_pasajero
FROM tf_entities  WHERE DATE(`ent_requested_time`) = '2015-03-03'
GROUP BY 'fleetId', taxiId ASC
order by taxiId ASC
```

In this [Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTlZP.jpg) I have to manually sum the time differences in a day, but I want to automatize the date-hour thing.

My wished result would be something like this, ordered by date and taxiId, for example:

```html
 Id|Taxi_Id| DATE  |time_wihtout_passenger|time_with_passenger| total_time |

 03|003001|2015-3-3|  00:30:00            |   01:02:00        |  01:32:00 

ent_fare_total | ent_distance_total |
   40,000      |     20,000
```

The time without passenger would be the difference between ent_requested_time and ent_pickup_time and the time with the passenger would be ent_pickup_time and ent_dropoff_time. Total time would be the SUM of the two of them.

Comment: Can you show us your approach(es) and/or a concrete query?

Comment: Please provide a well-formatted table instead of a screenshot of the table, and the desired result of the query. Also show us your best attempt at the query. Since you're new to [so] i'd reccommend you take the [tour] and check out the [ask] page to see how you can format a proper question

Comment: There are lots of answers if you search google or SO for "time difference mysql".

Comment: Just did it guys.